# DataTrigger Overflow exception

Tags: wpf, styles, datatemplate, datacontext, datatrigger

How can this be an overflow exception...?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ElementTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TypeConv}}" Value="{x:Type models:GroupModel}">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 0 0 0"></Setter>
                                <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding Model}"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Style>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                ...
             <StackPanel/>
<DataTemplate/>
```

For the reason: this is a template (with at least 25 UI contros) that normally needs Model A as datatype. the `DataTemplate` is a `ListvVew` `ItemTemplate`. But the datatype can be of type Model B. Model B has a property called 'Model', which is of type Model A.
So instead of copy pasting the whole block template and use style triggers or `DataTemplate` selectors, I just want to change the `DataContex`t (from "{Binding}" to "{Binding Model}")

anyone has some suggestions, a solution?

Thx!

EDIT: the `Converter` returns the type of the incoming value (the data object itself). that way i can know when Model B is using the template and so to change the DataContext.

Comment: I think the overflow is because by setting a data context of the control you will kick off the data trigger which sets the context which kicks off the data trigger...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work-around I would suggest to avoid possible recursion between setting the data context and triggering the `DataTrigger`:

Have both `ModelA` and `ModelB` implement a common interface called `IListViewModel` for example with a single property getter:

```
public interface IListViewModel
{
    ModelA Model {get;}
}
```

Then, `ModelA`'s implementation will return `this`, while `ModelB`'s implementation returns `this.ModelA` The `DataTemplate` simply binds to the `.Model`of whichever view model it's given.